# How to view what python requests is doing on browser

Tags: python, browser, python-requests

I just started experimenting with Requests with python to interact with different sites. However sometimes I want to see if the POST Requests I'm sending is actually working. Is there anyway to open a browser to see what is actually happening in the browser when I send POST requests?

Comment: See how to capture the browser http traffic here: https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204410413-Generating-a-HAR-file-for-troubleshooting

Comment: Get the return value see if status code is 2xx and if it was, dump the response in an HTML file. Open that file in browser to see what was returned.

Comment: You can check the response using `.text` returned by the server or you can check the status of the request. using 'status_code' method